# pgfplot - remove "top-border-line" and spacing between x-axis and bars

Tags: pgfplots

I am currently trying to create a bar chart using `pgfplots`.

My objective is to create a bar chart in which the bars are directly "sitting on top" of the x-axis AND there should be no "top-border-line" that limits my figure.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
     width  = 12cm,
     hide y axis,
     height = 8cm,
     bar width=20pt,
     symbolic x coords={2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015},
     nodes near coords,
     ]
     \addplot[ybar, fill=black] coordinates {
          (2010,1)
          (2011,3)
          (2012,11)
          (2013,15)
          (2014,29)
          (2015,14)
     };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much for your support! :-)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx), just add `axis x line=bottom` to remove top bar.

Comment: @salimbou The starred version `axis x line*` is better here so the effect will be only for the axis line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add

```
     axis x line*=bottom,
     ymin=0
```

to the `axis` options:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
     width  = 12cm,
     hide y axis,
     axis x line*=bottom,
     height = 8cm,
     bar width=20pt,
     symbolic x coords={2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015},
     nodes near coords,
     ymin=0
     ]
     \addplot[ybar, fill=black] coordinates {
          (2010,1)
          (2011,3)
          (2012,11)
          (2013,15)
          (2014,29)
          (2015,14)
     };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]